# How do I pass dataset attributes from an event target to a function parameter using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, event-handling

I have a function that dynamically creates a data visualization based on the object that is passed through as a parameter.

I am storing the name of the objects within an event target's data attribute. Then I set the function parameter based on that attribute.

Here is an example:

```
  <div>
      <button data-object="countries">click me</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      const countries = [
        { location: "United States", type: "country" },
        { location: "Canada", type: "country" },
      ];
      let button = document.querySelector("button");
      console.log(countries);

      const countriesFunction = (data) => {
        console.log(event.target.dataset.object);
      };

      button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        countriesFunction(event.target.dataset.object);
      });
```

The function "countriesFunction" does not recognize the event target's data attribute as the pre-defined object. It instead treats it as a string, which in my case throws an error.

I have tried JSON parsing, but I get a parsing error.

Is there a way to link up a target's data attribute value with an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-object` holds the text `countries`. To use that value as a variable, you'd need to use `eval`, which isn't desirable.

Instead put your `countries` into its own object, and use the dataset as part of an object path. You need to use square bracket notation for object member access. This lets you use any expression (like variable resolution) as the object member.

```
  const myData = {
   countries: [
    { location: "United States", type: "country" },
    { location: "Canada", type: "country" },
   ]
  };

  const countriesFunction = (data) => {
    console.log(myData[data]);
  };

  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    countriesFunction(event.target.dataset.object);
  });
```